# How to exclude/delete files only?

Tags: command-line, files

Is there a way to exclude all files, in all subfolders, and keep the folder structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you want to delete them...

`find -type f -delete`

This will delete all files in the current folder and all subfolders but leave the directories intact.

Comment: Alternatively, `find -type d` will show just the directory structure which could then be reproduced elsewhere with `mkdir -p`.